How to use stack in arm64 assembly
I was trying to write a nested loop and print a 10x10 grid of dots. And the assembler throws error when I am trying to use PUSH and POP commands in _print subroutine. Is this the right way to do it or am I doing something wrong. Please Help
.equ WIDTH, 10
.equ HEIGHT, 10

.data
DOT: .ascii "."
BLOCK: .ascii "$"
NEW_LINE: .ascii "\n"

.text
.global _start
_start:
_renderFrame:
    mov x0, HEIGHT
    mov x1, WIDTH
    bl _height

_height:
    cmp x0, 0
    beq _exit
    sub x0, x0, 1
    bl _width
    ldr x3, =NEW_LINE
    bl _print
    bl _height

_width:
    cmp x1, 0
    beq _height
    sub x1, x1, 1
    ldr x3, =DOT
    bl _print
    bl _width

_print:
    push {x0, x1, x2}
    mov x8, 0x40
    mov x0, 1
    mov x1, x3
    mov x2, 1
    svc 0
    pop {x0, x1, x2}
    ret

_exit:
    mov x8, 0x5d
    mov x0, 0
    svc 0

The error is as below
main.asm: Assembler messages:
main.asm:35: Error: unknown mnemonic `push' -- `push {x0,x1,x2}'
main.asm:41: Error: unknown mnemonic `pop' -- `pop {x0,x1,x2}'

Note: Before I tried to run assembly in macOS but it seems there is not much support articles online regarding macOS. So I am running this code in a Ubuntu Docker container with inbuilt assembler and linker. And the print and exit system calls are working fine.

Check the instruction set reference.  The push {...} instruction only exists on AArch32, not AArch64.  You can use stp instead.

Also be warned, the hardware might raise a stack alignment fault if sp isn't aligned to 0x10 bytes.

There are no push or pop instructions in ARM64 assembly.  Perhaps you have mixed it up with ARM32, which does have them.
To push and pop to the stack on ARM64, you can use the normal load and store instructions with a pre-decrement / post-increment addressing mode on the sp register.  Note that you must always adjust sp by multiples of 16 bytes, so it is convenient to push and pop two 64-bit registers at a time, using the ldp load-pair and stp store-pair instructions.
Example:
    stp x0, x1, [sp, #-16]!  // push x0 and x1
    ldp x0, x1, [sp], #16    // pop them again

If you want to push/pop more than two registers, you can either repeat this, or use the first/last store/load to adjust the stack pointer by the full amount needed for all the registers and then use non-pre/post-incrementing stores and loads for the others.
Example:
    stp x0, x1, [sp, #-32]!
    str x2, [sp, 16] // store x2 above x0 and x1
    ldr x2, [sp, 16]
    ldp x0, x1, [sp], #32


Unrelated, but the use of bl in your code seems confused.  bl is meant for function calls; it saves a return address into the link register x30 and then branches to the target address, which should be the first instruction of a function or subroutine.  The called function should then finish with ret to branch back to the address stored in x30, at which point execution continues with the instruction following the bl.  So it's unclear why you're using it for jumps to _width and _height which are not subroutines and don't return.  If you want an unconditional branch, use b instead of bl.
But in your code as follows:
_height:
    cmp x0, 0
    beq _exit
    sub x0, x0, 1
    bl _width
    ldr x3, =NEW_LINE // this and following lines are unreachable
    bl _print
    bl _height

Since _width has no ret instruction, it will not return (indeed it overwrites x30 by executing a bl of its own) and thus the code following bl _width cannot ever be executed.  So I think you need to put some more thought into your program's control flow.

Thank you mo much for you clear explanation, regarding the branch code what I was trying to do is a conditional return i.e return if a condition is true, I googled this requirement but didn't find any so was using bl. And in my mind I know this just increases the stack by storing those return addresses and I don't know any other way, thank you for telling about b I will use it from now on

My point is that, unlike x86 call, ARM bl doesn't push a return address to the stack.  Rather, it saves it in register x30 but the previous contents of x30 are overwritten, not saved anywhere.  It is your job to manually push x30 to the stack ahead of time, so that you don't lose the address you need to return to.

@masteronin99: I don't mean to be rude, but it sounds like you are trying to write this program largely by making assumptions and guesses about what the instructions do.  That is going to lead to a lot of confusion, frustration and bugs. Every single instruction has a precise description in the Architecture Reference Manual, and before using any instruction you should read its entry carefully to understand what it actually does.

@masteronin99: A good way to learn a new ISA is to see what compilers do for simple C functions.  e.g. write a function like void foo(int x){ if (x==0) return;  else global_var = 2; } (and maybe end with a tailcall or something if you want one of the paths through the function to not return at all.)   https://godbolt.org/z/aaz5jM33M
